# How do I ignore await/promises during webpack build

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I need to dynamically set a config option at runtime, so that the server can dictate options.  Currently I have:

**source.js**

```
const config = {"option1: "lindsay", "option2": "lohan"};
const myObject = myApp(config);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = [{
    entry: {
        "myfile": "./assets/js/source.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/js/",
        library: {
            name: "myLibrary",
            type: "var",
        }
    },
    mode: "production"
}]
```

This will successfully build a module that I can call via `myLibrary.myFunction()`

However, if I change the config to load at runtime;

**source.js**

```
const response = await fetch('./config.json');
const config = await response.json();
const myObject = myApp(config);
```

Then this is somehow interpreted differently at build (more output is shown) and when deployed it is now a promise, so I have to initiate it with something like

**random.js**

```
myLibrary.then((foo) => { foo.myFunction(); });
```

Is there any way to avoid this so that the `await` commands are ignored at build or deferred so that they are only called in the deployed environments.

I've played with `externals` but this appears to relate to `import`s etc. which I don't need to ignore.

Webpack is not erroring as it's building fine, it's just building something I'm not expecting.

**Versions**

I'm using:

```
webpack --version
  
Binaries:
  Node: 18.13.0 - /usr/bin/node
  npm: 9.2.0 - /usr/bin/npm
Packages:
  webpack: ^5.88.2 => 5.88.2 
  webpack-cli: ^5.1.4 => 5.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `source.js` has await at the top level it will return a promise anyway.

I think you should change the way you initialize the config.
For example, you could remove config as argument for myApp and initialize it separately:

```js
const myObject = myApp()

const getConfig = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('./config.json')
    const config = await response.json()

    myObject.setConfig(config)
}

getConfig()

export default myObject
```

Of course, initially "myObject' won't have the config until it will be fetched, but the object itself will be available.

And here I need to know how you app works.
There are couple of variants you can do it, but I need more information about your app to understand what the best solution.